# How to diagnose DataSource.Error when connecting to a custom ADO.NET provider?

Tags: c#, ado.net, powerbi

I have been working on an own implementation of ADO.NET. It works quite well from Visual Studio, etc. but now I want to use it in Power BI Desktop.

I have registered the provider in the machine.config already (both platforms) and have copied all relevant assemblies into the GAC. Now I was finally able to go around the first few error messages Power BI gave me, but now I am stuck at this one:

> DataSource.Error: An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: values'
>   Details:
>   DataSourceKind=AdoDotNet
>   DataSourcePath=MyOwnProvider/param1=Something

Now it seems to me this is a standard .NET error message, so that would be easy to solve if I knew where it went wrong. Unfortunately I have found no way to diagnose the issue yet. I have tried using Visual Studio to debug Power BI (which seems to have successfully loaded my assembly). I have tried to use DebugView and ProcMon to see what happens, but all failed to give me anything useful.

How to diagnose what actually went wrong? How to get a detailed log, call stack, or whatever?

Comment: (Blatant copy of my question on the [PowerBI forum here](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/DataSource-Error-when-connecting-to-ADO-NET-provider/td-p/85040))

Comment: How many methods do you have that accept an parameter called `values`?

Comment: None... It must be one of the internal methods of ADO.NET I guess. @rene

Comment: @Patrick Hofman Did you find the answer of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [question on the Power BI forum I posted](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/DataSource-Error-when-connecting-to-ADO-NET-provider/td-p/85040) next to my question here I got quite a helpful answer. I also have some personal observations I want to share.

First, from [Lydia](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/7126) on the forum:

> ... you can go to File -> Options and settings -> Options -> Diagnostics and click "enable tracing", then connect to your data source and check the detailed logs in the traces folder

This was very helpful since Power BI uses a separate process to kick off the data fetching. These processes, `Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40.exe` and `Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX45.exe` actually make the connection to the ADO.NET data sources. If you have your provider running, you can also attach to them in order to trace the execution.

Another thing I found helpful was using a separate file to write the tracing in. I have used an event handler to `AppDomain.UnhandledException` to write to a trace file. This also gave me some bugs in the Power BI code, which was very helpful to diagnose what went wrong beyond my own provider.